# How can I use PHPExcel to update a chart with different data?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to read an Excel template and then write another  excel file based on that model.
In my model I have 2 sheets: the first one named "Data" contains sample Data. The 2nd sheet contains a graph using the data of the first sheet.

What I'm trying to do:

- replace the data of the first sheet with the new data so that the Graph automatically change.

The problem is that when I generate my excel file based on the template, the graph does'nt always appear. And when it does, there is a popup saying that he had to repair the file (I think that's because the formula of my chart refers to the data that is being replaced. PHPExcel override the data so the chart can't load).

Is there another way to achieve this with PHPExcel?

Also, I already included

```
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

and

```
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
```

If something isn't clear don't hesitate to ask, I don't want to put too much useless informations for you.